# recreate/clone entire div with vue on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to figure this out but haven't had success with any straight methods yet, but I simply want to be able to click the link 'Add another zone' and then on that click recreate my entire div with id "vueAC" below the existing one.

What is the best way to handle this with the structure I have:

```
    <div id="vueAC" class="uk-grid">
    <div class="uk-width-2-10"  >
        <input size="4" type="text" name="mapNumber">
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-6-10">
      <input style="width:100%" type="text" placeholder="what are you looking for?" v-model="searchString" v-on:keyup="autoComplete" class="form-control">
      <div class="panel-footer componentList" v-if="results.length">
       <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" v-for="result in results">
           <a v-on:click="saveAttribute(result)">@{{ result.attribute_value }}</a>
        </li>
       </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-width-2-10" style="border: 1px solid black; height:50px; width: 50px; margin: 0 auto;" >
    
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a v-on:click="addDiv">Add another zone</a>
</div>

new Vue({
  components: {
  },
  el: "#vueAC",
  data(){
   return {
    searchString: '',
    results: []
   }
  },
  methods: {
   autoComplete(){
    this.results = [];
    console.log(this.searchString);
    if(this.searchString.length > 2){
     axios.get('/search',{params: {searchString: this.searchString}}).then(response => {
      this.results = response.data;
      console.log(this.results);
      console.log(this.searchString);
     });
    }
   },

   addDiv(){
    // Here I want to recreate the entire div with ID vueAC right below the existing one
   }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommed you to add a key to the div `vueAC` whenever you want to re-render the div you just need to update the key.

```html
<div id="vueAC" class="uk-grid" :key="myKey">
</div>
```

With this, you could use a number as the key then just increment it.

```js
new Vue({
data(){
 return {
   myKey: 0,
 }
},
methods: {
 addDiv(){
   // Do whatever you need to do.

   this.myKey++;
 }
}
})
```

For more information you can see the docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense in terms of keeping uniqueness. But how do I actually clone the elements of the div?

Comment: In that case I would recommend to have an array of the data you need to clone and in that case you can use a loop to print all the elements in the div `<div id="vueAC" class="uk-grid" v-for="(data, index) in myDataobject" :key="index"> </div>`. With this approach you just need to manipulate the array and Vue will do the render.

Answer (score 0):

`addDiv` should be outside the component as a parent component method. In the parent component. You should have an array of zones in data. Once you click `addDiv` append an empty zone with empty info into the `this.zones`. Loop over each zone with v-for.